# Recomendación sobre algún software gratuito para hacer diagramas Entidad/Relación con notación Chen

Tags: base-de-datos

Quería recomendación sobre algún software gratuito para hacer `diagramas entidad/relación` con notación Chen. Si puede ser que sean exportables mejor. Muchas gracias

Comment: A que te refieres con exportables?

Comment: Según he podido leer creo que hay programas que permiten exportar el diagrama a los gestores de bases de datos para generar la base de datos a partir del diagrama. Aunque no estoy seguro de esto ya que conozco bien poco del tema.

Comment: MySQL Workbench tiene un editor de diagramas ER bastante bueno: https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Comment: Perdón, me faltó especificar que necesito que sea con la notación Chen. Por lo que he visto MySQL Workbench trabaja con otra notación. ¿Sabes si también se puede utilizar con la Chen? Ahora edito la pregunta.

Comment: Hola miguel, desde mi punto de vista tu pregunta está basada en opiniones. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Comment: Preguntas basadas en recomendaciones u opiniones Terminan cerradas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te recomiendo [www.draw.io](https://www.draw.io/) es online, gratuito y te permite exportar a múltiples formatos.

También tiene la notación que precisas y es de fácil aprendizaje.

Comment: Idealmente considera no responder por favor a preguntas basadas en opiniones pues estás terminan cerradas